# jQuery parse xml vica-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a javascript which has to parse xml on the file, and than support to download the xml as well. It is working like charm if the xml origin is a file, but I am having trouble if I would like to do it from a string:

```
var origFriendList = $.parseXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FriendList ver="3"><aaa>aa</aaa></FriendList>');
var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($(origFriendList));
```

The error what I am reciving is: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**

Speaking Frankly I have no idea what could be the solution here. Once again the code is working if I am getting the things like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/Friends.xml',
dataType: "xml",
success: function (xml) {
var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($(xml));
    }
});
```

So it could be sync/async issue as well, but I do not know how to catch when parsing is ready:) Any help would be great... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are passing a jQuery wrapper object(`$(origFriendList)`) to `serializeToString`, which is expecting a Node instance.

So just pass the XML document returned by `$.parseXML()` to `serializeToString`

```
var origFriendList = $.parseXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FriendList ver="3"><aaa>aa</aaa></FriendList>');
var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(origFriendList);

console.log(xmlString)
```